# Rails ActiveAdmin register, wrapping another resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have 2 activeadmin resources, both are subclasses of a model, using STI. For example:

base_model.rb

```
class BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

male_model.rb

```
class MaleModel < BaseModel

end
```

female_model.rb

```
class FemaleModel < BaseModel

end
```

admin/male_model.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register MaleModel do
  menu :parent => "Models", :label => "Male Model"

  # A big long custom form follows...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

admin/female_model.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register FemaleModel do
  menu :parent => "Models", :label => "Female Model"

  # The SAME big long custom form follows...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

What would be the correct way to render the same form, but create a record of a different subclass, either MaleModel or FemaleModel?

What I'm doing now is maintaining 2 activeadmin resources with almost exactly the same (bulky) code within. Totally unDRY. Please share what you've done in this situation.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't try this but you could define an `@object` variable in the controller:

```
controller do
    before_filter :set_object, :only => [:new, :edit]
    ....
    def set_object
        @object = MaleModel.find(params[:id]) rescue MaleModel.new
    end
end
```

And then you could render a form and use the variable `@object` instead of `@male_model` or `@female_model`.

```
form :partial => "models/form"

# app/views/models/_form.html.erb
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @object] do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs %>
    <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hmmm... I thought about doing this. I do wonder if it's the only way. I don't actually NEED to render a custom html form. Still, it might be the most straightforward solution.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to tell activeadmin to render a form of another registered resource if that's what you wanted to do. And if it's a big long custom form maybe it's better to render a partial.